# Generic controller inside razor class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, class-library

I have a **generic controlle**r that's inside a **razor class library** referenced in a net core **web app**. Problem: When I launch the web app and try to navigate to `/MyFeature/User`, it still doesn't recognize that endpoint at all. Note that when I remove the generic type from the controller and its constructor, the endpoint `/MyFeature/User` works just fine. 
**Here is the controller:**

```
 [Area("MyFeature")]
    [Authorize]
    public class UserController<TIdentityUser> : Controller
        where TIdentityUser : IdentityUser
    {
```

Next, I'm trying to make the web app accept controllers that have generic types :

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ......

            services.AddControllerFeatureProvider(Configuration);
            ....

        }
```

Here is the implementation of AddControllerFeatureProvider **from the razor class library**:

```
public static void AddControllerFeatureProvider(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
        {
            services.AddMvcCore().ConfigureApplicationPartManager(manager =>
            {
                manager.FeatureProviders.Add(new MyControllerFeatureProvider());
            });
        }
```

MyControllerFeatureProvider makes the app accept controllers with generic types. I've debugged that part and it works fine. ***UserController`1 goes into the breakpoint and it returns IsController as true.***
But still, the endpoint doesn't work at all.

```
public class MyControllerFeatureProvider : ControllerFeatureProvider
    {
        protected override bool IsController(TypeInfo typeInfo)
        {
            var isController = base.IsController(typeInfo);

            if (!isController && typeInfo.Name.Contains("Test") || typeInfo.Name.Contains("User"))
            {
                isController = typeInfo.Name.EndsWith("Controller`1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            }

            return isController;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did you define `MyControllerFeatureProvider`?

Comment: edited my post. You can check